# NestJS Error Debug Failure. False expression: Too many nodes written to output

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm starting a backend Nestjs v10 project and I'm using Automapper:
[image]

According to the [documentation](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/misc/transformer-plugin), to avoid decorating classes with @AutoMap() that becomes verbose, I can use a transformer plugin that enables automapper to run a before transformer looking for .entity.ts .model.ts, etc. files and add them to a list for mappings.

So NestJS CLI section says: "To use this plugin with nestjs/cli, modify your nest-cli.json". I did it as you can see below:

[image]

However when I run: nest start, the following error is thrown.

[image]

If I remove the entry, the command runs ok:

[image]

Thanks for any help